# averageif excel returning div/0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, divide-by-zero

I am trying to use the averageif command in excel to average the construction years, column c for each puma value, column h. It is returning div/0. Please see image below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Excel Image]

Comment: You have your first and third criteria switched.  The first should be the condition and third the column in which you find the values.  Also you can use the full column, the first row will not meet the criteria so it will not be a problem: `=AVERAGEIF(H:H,3701,C:C)`

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think we got to year 3701!